# Breaking the program when an error occurs python networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I'm using the networkx package in python in order to get the distance between a point and a set of points.

```
distance_in_meters = nx.shortest_path_length(G, origin_node, destination_node, weight='length')
```

The thing is there will be a couple of destinantion nodes and some of then can't be reached from the origin node. When this happens an error occurs and the program stops, my goal would be for the program to keep running and when a path isn't found the variable distance_in_meters would be saved as "none".

Is there any direct and easy way to do this?

Comment: I suspect you are looking for the [handling exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) section of the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to condition the calculation on path existing:

```py
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edge(1, 3)
G.add_edge(2, 4)

for origin_node in (1, 2):
    for destination_node in (3, 4):
        if nx.has_path(G, origin_node, destination_node):
            distance_in_meters = nx.shortest_path_length(
                G, origin_node, destination_node, weight="length"
            )
        else:
            distance_in_meters = None
        print(origin_node, destination_node, distance_in_meters)
# 1 3 1
# 1 4 None
# 2 3 None
# 2 4 1
```